# Disable Session regeneration in Yii2

Tags: session, cookies, yii2

I have an Yii2 application which is doing most of the work through an external API, including the authentication and most of the read/update requests.

After the login I store a some encrypted values in the session, and store the encryption-key for them in a cookie.

The problem is, the cookie (or the session?).. expires after 30+ min of inactivity .. but the session is automatically regenerated (user is not prompted to login),
but the retrieving of the values is broken.

The main problem is it is hard to reproduce (it usually happens if you let the page open over night).

I have set both the  **remember me** and the **cookie expire time** to **0**
but it seems there are more options that need to be addressed.

Here is the function that store / retrieve the data from the session.

```
public static function storeData($stored_data)
    {
        $security = Yii::$app->getSecurity();
        $key = $security->generateRandomKey();
        $encrypted = $security->encryptByKey($stored_data, $key);

        Yii::$app->getSession()->set('stored_data', $encrypted);
        Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new Cookie([
            'name' => 'key',
            'value' => $key,
            //'expire' => time() + 60*60*24*30, 
        ]));
    }


    private static function getData()
    {
        $security = Yii::$app->getSecurity();
        $encrypted = Yii::$app->getSession()->get('stored_data');
        $key = Yii::$app->request->cookies->get('key');

        $stored_data= $security->decryptByKey($encrypted, $key);

        return $stored_data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this cookie generating code instead of your

```
public static function storeData($stored_data)
{
    $security = Yii::$app->getSecurity();
    $key = $security->generateRandomKey();
    $encrypted = $security->encryptByKey($stored_data, $key);

    Yii::$app->getSession()->set('stored_data', $encrypted);
    $cookie = new CHttpCookie([
        'name' => 'key',
        'value' => $key,
    ]);
    $cookie->expire = time()+60*60*24*180; 
    Yii::app()->request->cookies['key'] = $cookie;
    Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(Yii::app()->request->cookies['key']);
}
```

And inside your config/main.php

```
return array(
    'components'=>array(
        'request'=>array(
            'enableCookieValidation'=>true,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Get more details [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/152/cookie-management-in-yii/)

Comment: Your code looks like mix of Yii1 and Yii2 code. The question is about Yii2.

Comment: Did you followed the link i shared. It's for Yii 2 only

Comment: I don't get your point, you just assign the new cookie to `->request->cookies['some_key']` and the immediately read it from there. Is there some magic in the setter/getter ?  and how is this suppose to fix the **session restore** problem ?

Comment: @d.raev session is not problem in your script, as you have told in your description your session is regenerated and you dont have to login again. But retreaving of the values is broken so some how i have assigned it to new cookie and again assesed it for values that's it.